# Spring Data: how works Pageable together with @Query? (Interface Projection)

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am working with `Spring Data` for the `2.0.6.RELEASE` version

I am confused about the following about pagination and projection

The domain class is named `Persona` working with `lombok` and annotated with `JPA` (`@Entity` etc ..)

I have the following about projection:

```
public interface PersonaProjection {

    String getId();
    String getNombre();
    String getApellido();
    Date getFecha();

}
```

About the repository I have the following:

```
interface PersonaDataJpaCrudRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Persona, String> {

    Page<PersonaProjection> findAllProjectedBy(Pageable pageable);

}
```

Until here all work fine.

The `@Controller` has this body:

```
@GetMapping(path="/complete", produces=MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public String findAllComplete(Pageable pageable, Model model){
    logger.info("findAllComplete ...");
    Page<PersonaProjection> personasPage = personaService.findAll(pageable);
    model.addAttribute("personasPage", personasPage);
    return "persona/findAllComplete";
}
```

The view is based with `Thymeleaf` and shows the data how is expected

Practically from three days ago I was working with the following:

```
@Query("SELECT p.id, p.nombre, p.apellido, p.fecha FROM Persona p")
Page<PersonaProjection> findAllProjectedBy(Pageable pageable);
```

Observe it has a `@Query` just to visual purposes. It to help to understand quickly what fields are retrieved.

And worked fine, but just **until** today without any variation practically the view for that fields remains in `blank`, none exception thrown, through the console through some special variations of the `@Controller` method I can confirm:

```
Page request [number: 0, size 10, sort: UNSORTED] 
    PageNumber: 0, PageSize: 10, Offset: 0 
Page 1 of 11 containing com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84 instances 
    Number: 0, NumberOfElements: 10 
    Size: 10, TotalElements: 107, TotalPages: 11 
    PageNumber: 0, PageSize: 10, Offset: 0
```

The output shown above in the previous three days appears *with* and *without* the `Query` addition.

After to do a research I found the following example for this class:

- [CustomerRepository.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/projections/CustomerRepository.java)

Where it has the following method:

```
    /**
     * Projection interfaces can be used with manually declared queries, too. Make sure you alias the projects matching
     * the projection fields.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Query("select c.firstname as firstname, c.lastname as lastname from Customer c")
Collection<CustomerProjection> findsByProjectedColumns();
```

Observe this note:

> Make sure you alias the projects matching the projection fields.

Thus if I use:

```
@Query("SELECT p.id as id, p.nombre as nombre, p.apellido as apellido, p.fecha as fecha FROM Persona p")
Page<PersonaProjection> findAllProjectedBy(Pageable pageable);
```

Works but observe is **redundant**, it about that the alias is the same than the field name.

Thus following questions:

- Why the first `@Query` version works some days ago and now no?. Here my big confusion. (I am assuming that `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84 instances` is involved)
- Why is mandatory use this alias `as` within the `@Query`? It is **not** documented in the [4.3.11. Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) section, even more there is no sample showing an `interface projection` working together with a `@Query`

Comment: Did you change the underlying database some days ago?

Comment: Yes and no, nothing about the `schema` it remains being the same, just added or inserted  around `100` fakes records. Originally was 5 records, now 107. Just to test the view about pagination

Comment: I meant the version of the db, different DB, you tested it with H2 and now you switched to a normal DB or something like this

Comment: All in `runtime` with `MySQL`, I interact manually with the web app through a web browser. Testing is with `H2`. But this situation only is reflected in the view, where the expected data does not appear, that part of the `html` page appears in blank or no data, the rest data about pagination, amount of records, etc appears normally. Thus all about the proxy data does not appear in the view.